# 2D illustration to animate into 3D gif?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, 3d, animation, gif, adobe-after-effects

How can I create any 2D animation to do this type of animation? What programs can I use?

I am looking to make a flat, circular-bound illustration into a 3D coin (with a different back) and rotate constantly, just like this statue GIF.

I have AfterEffects and Cinema4D. I am not too well-versed in these platforms. It would be great if you can recommend the best workflow for this. :)[image]

Comment: Map 2D artwork to a 3D model.. record 3D model spinning to a movie file. Open movie, export as gif. -- these are broad steps.

Comment: If you're not versed in AE and C4D then you'll need to learn at least one of these well and the basics of the other. Too broad to fit in a proper answer here.

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell you what apps were originally used to create this, but *general* workflow-wise, this was a 3D model (high likelihood it started as a photogrammetric scan) created with a **3D DCC** (**D**igital **C**ontent **C**reation) tool such as [**Modo**](https://www.foundry.com/products/modo), [**Blender**](https://www.blender.org/), [**3DS**](https://www.autodesk.com/products/3ds-max/overview), [**Maya**](https://www.autodesk.com/products/maya/overview), [**C4D**](https://www.maxon.net/en/products/cinema-4d/overview/) or [**Lightwave**](https://www.lightwave3d.com/), with a simple **NPR** (**N**on-**P**hoto-**R**eal) edge shader applied to it, which then had a turntable ***(1)*** animation created, either by rotating a virtual camera around the model or by rotating the model. There was no illumnation or GI applied - only the **NPR** edge shader (not even a toon cel-shader or half-tone shader) and this turntable animation was then converted to a `.gif` file.

***(1)*** Turntables are a commonly-used export in the 3D generalist world for small assets, as they enable the 3D Generalist's modeling or digital sculpting skills to be easily highlighted in the least time: often, the artist will give one complete rotation with the given desired shader, then one rotation with "wires" (wireframe view) to allow the viewer to assess how clean their topology + edge flow is.

Hope this helps.